# Constructor declaring database connection not run after PHP 8 upgrade

Tags: php, database, pdo

I am getting an error when I connecting to database.
It was working before the hosting website decide to remove php 7 and add php 8.3

This is the codes of the connection function:

```php
class App {

    function App() {
        include('dbInfo.php');
        try {
            $this->dbConn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbName",$dbUser,$dbPass, array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
              ));
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            die("ERROR: ".$e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    function getConfig() {
        $sql = $this->dbConn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `config`');
        $sql->execute();
        $result = $sql->fetchAll();
        return $result;
    }

}
```

And this is the error msg:

> Warning: Undefined property: App::$dbConn in /customers/b/b/1/944.dk/httpd.www/server/dataBase/myServer.php on line 29 
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /customers/b/b/1/944.dk/httpd.www/server/dataBase/myServer.php:29 Stack trace: 
> #0 /customers/b/b/1/944.dk/httpd.www/server/dataBase/myServer.php(16): App->getConfig() 
> #1 /customers/b/b/1/944.dk/httpd.www/server/templates/get.php(5): App->getAll() 
> #2 /customers/b/b/1/944.dk/httpd.www/server/index.php(3): include_once('/customers/b/b/...') 
> #3 {main} thrown in /customers/b/b/1/944.dk/httpd.www/server/dataBase/myServer.php on line 29

The line 29 is this:

```
$sql = $this->dbConn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `config`');
```

Comment: If that code is in a CLASS then please show it as such, otherwise thats a set of functions and there is no `$this` to a set of functions

Comment: Can you post the class level code as well as the relevant methods?

Comment: Yes it is in class `class App(){.....}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [PHP 8.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php) on, method with the same name as the class is no longer treated as constructor:

```php
class Bar {
    public function Bar() {
        // treated as regular method in PHP 8.0
    }
}
```

That's why your function `App()` was never run to create the `$this->dbConn`.

You need to rename it as `function __construct()` to make it a constructor.

---

Edit: *Previously refer the change to PHP 5.3.3. The change on PHP 5.3.3 only affected namespace classes. The change on PHP 8.0 affects event the class without namespace.*

Answer (score 3):

`function App() {` is old style `__construct`

In PHP8 it is no longer called automatically - leading to missing class parameter.

Rename `function App()` to `public function __construct()`.

Check [Old-style constructors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)